# How can i get String from strings.xml in a class?

Tags: java, android, computer-science

i have been trying to use this code for my application. Im trying to call this class in strings.xml but i couldn't figure it out. How can i call the class in strings.xml?

public class Sorular  {

```
    public String Sorular[] = {
            "When did Facebook came out?",
            "Who is a Google Developer?",
            "Whitch one is the first Smartphone?"
    };

    public String Secenekler[][] = {
            {"2002", "2003", "2004"},
            {"Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Larry Page"},
            {"Iphone", "Samsung", "Nokia"}
    };

    public String DogruCevap[] = {
            "2004",
            "Larry Page",
            "Iphone"
    };

    public String getQuestion ( int a){
        String soru = Sorular[a];
        return soru;
    }

    public String getchoice1 ( int a){
        String secenek = Secenekler[a][0];
        return secenek;
    }

    public String getchoice2 ( int a){
        String secenek = Secenekler[a][1];
        return secenek;
    }

    public String getchoice3 ( int a){
        String secenek = Secenekler[a][2];
        return secenek;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer ( int a){
        String cevap = DogruCevap[a];
        return cevap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you find how to add array in string.xml

```
<string-array name="Sorular">
    <item>When did Facebook came out?</item>
    <item>Who is a Google Developer?</item>
    <item>Whitch one is the first Smartphone?</item>
</string-array>
```

Here you can find how to call from java

```
public String getQuestion (Context context, int a){
    String soru = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sorular)[a];
    return soru;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your strings inside string.xml file, and then reference them from your code with the following call:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.word);
```